# Provide iterator while generating power set

Tags: c#, algorithms, optimization

I have written a code in C# to generate the power set of a given input list of integers.

```
public List<List<int>> GeneratePowerSet(List<int> Set)
{
    int setCount = Set.Count;
    int powerSetCount = 1 << setCount;

    // Temporary list to hold the all subsets
    List<List<int>> subsets = new List<List<int>>();

    // Outer loop running 2^n times
    for (int i = 0; i < powerSetCount; i++)
    {
        // Inner loop running n times to check if j-th bit is set or not
        for (int j = 0; j < setCount; j++)
        {
            // Temporary list to hold the current subset
            List<int> subset = new List<int>();

            // Check if j-th bit of i is 1 or no
            if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0)
            {
                subset.Add(Set[j]);
            }
            subsets.Add(subset);
        }
    }

    return subsets;
}
```

---

As seen above I am making 2 temporary input lists which is causing extra overhead while generating the subsets.

Also for larger inputs I have observed it takes too long to compute the power sets.

**How can I rewrite this method using the iterator pattern so that each time it yields out the current value without having me to make a temporary list.**

---

**Update:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GeneratePowerSet(List<int> Set)
{
    int setCount = Set.Count;
    int powerSetCount = 1 << setCount;


    // Outer loop running 2^n times
    for (int i = 0; i < powerSetCount; i++)
    {
        // Inner loop running n times to check if j-th bit is set or not
        for (int j = 0; j < setCount; j++)
        {
            // Check if j-th bit of i is 1 or no
            if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0)
            {
                yield return new[] { Set[j] };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Phrasing it in a different way, the power set of {} is {}.   The power set of {A} is the power set of {} with every combination of A in each set ({}, {A}).  The power set of {A, B} is the power set of {A} (so {}, {A}) with every combination of B in each set ({}, {A}, {B}, {A, B}).   You can see how this might be written recursively.  If you worry that you'll hit the limit for recursion, worry not.  The universe will end or memory will be consumed before you can generate a powerset of that size.

Comment: @Neil will the recursive method work for large inputs ? or is it the same performing with the bit method above

Comment: You only ever have recursion of depth `Set.Count`. You'll probably run out of heap space building the full powerset eagerly before iterating lazily would run out of stack space

Comment: @Neil if we foreach over it lazily and build it will it still run out of memory ?

Comment: If you are asking about processing one subset at a time, yes, for some large-ish input size. There's always a maximum amount of data any given computer can hold. However the *time* needed to process the largest input will be *huge*, potentially in the order of *years*, or potentially in the order of *lifetimes of the universe*

Comment: @KunalMukherjee You could create a generator for this as well.  For the powerset of N, have a number starting with 0 increase until 2^N.  For each number, map its bits to each item in the powerset, increase the number, and return that powerset.  Done like this, it consumes very little memory and it's generated on demand.

Comment: @Neil something like the update ?

Comment: @Kunal The way I'm thinking, you wouldn't need but one loop.  Simply everytime the method is called, you compute the power set pertaining to the current value of the private integer member (looping through each bit), you increment the number for the next call, then you return the power set that you computed.  The constructor would take as a value the number N representing the power set amount.

Comment: Your attempts are only ever generating subsets with one element, which is only a tiny fraction of the elements of a powerset

Comment: @Neil can you show with a code-sample the approach you're thinking?

Comment: `yield Set.Where((_, j) => (i & (1 << j)) != 0);` instead of your `j` loop.

Comment: Note that your method is limited to 30 elements, as `1 << 31` is greater than the maximum `int`. That's probably a good thing. If it takes 1 nanosecond to process a subset, the powerset of 30 elements will take 1000 seconds, i.e. ~15 minutes

Comment: @caleth So we can use ulong right ? Or is there a better way out ? Int 32 will overflow after I shift to 32 bits

Comment: Yes, if you want to spend *a million years* processing subsets. I meant microsecond above, nanosecond is unrealistic for generating and processing a subset of ~30 elements. I calculated for 10^-6s per element

Comment: @Caleth But it will just yield it on the fly right ? it won't store it in the memory ?

Comment: What makes you worry that it will? And why do you not care about the ridiculous length of time it would take? If you don't care about the maximum runtime, use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, not `long`

Comment: @Caleth So what in your opinion is the most optimal to generate power sets ?

Comment: It fundamentally doesn't matter. *Using* them will take all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have a powerset for a set of `N-1` elements, then the powerset for `N` elements returns twice as many, those with the `Nth` element and those without. We can implement this recursively, as follows.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class SetExtensions
{
    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PowersetFrom<T>(List<T> elems, int current)
    {
        if (current == elems.Count) 
        { 
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            yield break;
        }

        var single = new T[]{ elems[current] };

        foreach (var next in PowersetFrom(elems, current + 1))
        {
            yield return single.Concat(next);
            yield return next;
        }
    } 

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Powerset<T>(this List<T> elems)
    {
         return PowersetFrom(elems, 0);
    }
}
```

Stepping through, for `Powerset({1, 2, 3})`

```
PowersetFrom({1, 2, 3}, 0)
calls PowersetFrom({1, 2, 3}, 1)
    calls PowersetFrom({1, 2, 3}, 2)
        calls PowersetFrom({1, 2, 3}, 3)
            which returns {{}}
        which yields {3}, {}
    which yields {2, 3}, {3}, {2}, {}
which yields {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2}, {1}, {}
```

An alternative, using `BigInteger`, looks similar to what you have

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GeneratePowerSet(List<int> Set)
{
    // Outer loop running 2^n times
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.Zero; i < (BigInteger.One << Set.Count); i++)
    {
        yield return Set.Where((_, j) => (i & (BigInteger.One << j)) != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: so we are not checking whether the bits are set or no ?

Comment: No, we simply yield every sub-sequence twice

Comment: can you provide a visualization, its tough to get a intuition for it

Comment: this code is not building, I think we need to return  `return Enumerable.Single(Enumerable.Empty<T>());`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee my C# is rusty, I corrected the errors

Comment: why both yield return and yield break is needed in the base case ?

Comment: You want to end the method, having first returned an empty collection for the base case. i.e. `{{}}` is not the same as `{}`

Comment: So it runs 2^n times right ?

Comment: Something iterating over this will see all 2^n subsets, yes